# CURRENTLY IN USE ELSEWHERE while using aforge in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, aforge

i´m having some troubles while using DirectShow with aforge to capture images from my webcam and showing them in a picturebox, i always get the same error, even after several tries.

This is my code.

```
public void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs EventArgs)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)EventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    }
```

but i have also tried this

```
public void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs EventArgs)
    {
        lock (EventArgs)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)EventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        }
    }
```

and this

```
public void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs EventArgs)
    {
        lock (pictureBox1)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)EventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        }
    }
```

no matter what i try, i alway get this error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZPZI.png)

my actual code is this, and it works, but i do not like it 'cos it is only a way to ignore the problems, i would like to solve this.

```
public void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs EventArgs)
    {
        try
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)EventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        }
        catch 
        {
        }
    }
```

thank you very much for your help.
My best regards,
Sergio David Mercado Vera

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why this is necessary, but you should use Invoke:

```
public void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs EventArgs)
    {
        Invoke(new Action(() =>
               {
            pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)EventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        }));
    }
```